# NoClassDefFoundError on Hello World

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a very simple program and running into errors. I made a very simple helloworld java program, and am unable to run it from terminal on a mac. I have check to make sure classpath is set properly, and am confused as to why it is not running.

**Here is the program:**

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

**Here is the terminal commands:**

```
Last login: Thu May  2 12:01:50 on ttys000
172-26-125-179:~ rohan$ cd /Users/rohan/Desktop 
172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$ ls
Hello.java
172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$ echo $CLASSPATH

172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$ export CLASSPATH=/Users/rohan/Desktop
172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/rohan/Desktop
172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$ java Hello.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
172-26-125-179:Desktop rohan$
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!
**UPDATE Ignore the prior case, this is a better view of my problem:**

```
Last login: Thu May  2 13:05:17 on ttys000
172-26-125-179:~ rohan$ cd /Users/rohan/Dropbox/Current/ds/lab6 
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ ls
Hello.java
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ cat Hello.java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ echo $CLASSPATH

172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ export CLASSPATH=/Users/rohan/Dropbox/Current/ds/lab6 
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/rohan/Dropbox/Current/ds/lab6
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ javac Hello.java
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$ java Hello.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
172-26-125-179:lab6 rohan$
```

Comment: Where is the class file created?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it's not; that's the problem. Look at the `ls` output.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

$ javac Hello.java

$ java Hello

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile it.

```
javac Hello.java
java Hello
```

The first command generates a file, `Hello.class`, in your current working directory (Desktop in your example). The second runs the Java program with the main class `Hello`.

Note the absence of `.java` in the second command. If you write `java Hello.java`, the JRE looks for a class called `java` in a package `Hello` (note the output: no class found in "Hello/java").

If `javac` gives you an error then you probably need to install the Java Development Kit (JDK) as well as the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

Answer (score 0):

When running Java, don't include ".java" in the classname you want to run.  Try

```
java Hello
```

From the `ls` output, it's not even compiled yet.  You must of course compile it first.

```
javac Hello.java
```

**EDIT**

The addition to the question states now that it *is* compiled successfully with `javac`.  But now the command `java Hello.class` is being run.  Don't include ".class" (or the previous ".java") in the Java class name to run.

The solution is still:

```
java Hello
```

Comment: That's not the problem. It's not compiled.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether it's compiled or not.  But "java Hello.java" is certainly wrong.  But I'll update my answer anyway...

Comment: it *is* clear; he `ls`es the directory and there's only one file.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `ls` output.  Sigh.  Changing my answer again.

Comment: Hi guys, I checked on it I was doing it backwards. Though when I try to do it on another file, i run into errors, I will try to update the question

Comment: @rohan123, I've edited my answer in response to the additional information you've added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

java programs are compiled using javac compiler. it comes bundled with jdk. you need to install jdk then compile it like

```
 javac Hello.java
```

it will generate a class file Hello.class then you can run the class file as

```
java Hello
```